# Copy specific row and delete blank

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub vova()

Dim S_path As String
Dim S_name1  As String, S_nameW1 As String
S_path = "S:\"
S_path = Trim(S_path) + Trim(Worksheets("1").Range("G6").Value) + ".xlsx"
 
 
Range("A1:N27").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
S_nameW1 = ActiveWorkbook.name
S_name1 = ActiveSheet.name


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 2
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 35
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 13
Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 15
Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 15

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=S_path, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Can someone help me, need the macro to delete blank raws(if 1-5 is filled) then 6-15 is deleted and macro creates new workbook with needed raws

[image]

created workbook should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 15
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With S_name1 
 for i = .range("A1048576").end(xlup).row to 9 Step -1

   if .cells(i, 2) = "" Then
     .rows(i & ":" & i).delete
   End if

 Next

End With

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=S_path, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

This will basically loop backward from the last used cell in column A till row 9, and delete the row if there is nothing in column B (which appears to be the case in your screenshot).

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Comment: getting this error and forgot to say that in column b there are drop down lists and formulas in columns c,d,e